# Render and view API response file to UI in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to render and display a file (pdf) which is a response of an API call. If this is possible ? If yes how?.

My sample code snippet for get file from an API call is given below.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  pdfSrc;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileLoad('fileUrl');
  }

  file: File;
  loaded = false;
  fileLoad(url) {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.file = data['_body'];
        this.loaded = true;
      })
  }

}
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What type of file? html, pdf ...?

Comment: Its a PDF file.

Comment: @Ajmal What type of file you want to render?
In browser you can only render files for which you have installed extensions. For example If you are using chrome, for pdf you might have default extension or adobe reader extension. In other case you can't

Comment: Check out this npm module `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer`

Comment: @umar. I want to render a pdf file.

Comment: @ShanilFernando  i'm already using ng2-pdf-viewer for viewing . Its work for a pdf file from local system but not work for file from API response . actually i want to know to  how to use it with API responced file

Comment: Internally he is using PDFJS library to render the pdf data. you can check ng2-pdf-viewer internal component to see how it internally renders [https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/master/src/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.ts](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/master/src/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.ts) and do it accordingly.

Comment: @ShanilFernando . in that i this he is referring the path of the file .I have the file in a file object. so can i load this file without referring the  path of the file.

Comment: Actually it can be binary data of the pdf which I hope what api call returned. check pdfjs documentation [https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/2b82eb0161196fe5b6577dc47b8df520d817057f/src/display/api.js#L158](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/2b82eb0161196fe5b6577dc47b8df520d817057f/src/display/api.js#L158)

Comment: @Ajmalsha What you can do is create temporary link of file from Blob object as following
file = new Blob(['blob data'], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
let link = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
Then use this link in ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: @umar its worked . thanks .